# Late payment wages due

Tags: employment

I started a new job recently and its monthly pay,today is my pay day but its 9pm and still have received my wages? I've spoke to some of the other employees and apparently it's the same every month. I'm starting to worry what I've let myself in for. Any advice would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: In what country/state are you located in? So you're saying that your pay is going to be one day late? One or two days late is not a lot. Personally, I would just email HR/payroll to let them know. Anyway, is the company having financial problems? Or do you think it's just incompetency?

Comment: Monthly pay? Aren't these made between the 1st day of the month and up to the 10th or more depending on the country, local labor laws and regulations and company's habits? A couple of days isn't that much though. You may add a country tag please.

Comment: What does "apparently it's the same every month." mean?  Do the wages get paid 1 day late, 2 days late etc?  I would expect that they do get paid sometime otherwise no one would work there

Comment: VTC - There can be many reasons why pay is late coming in. Different Payroll systems, different Banks etc. We don't know the minutiae of the company or your banking provider so cannot reallyanswer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no indication it is late.

In many countries bank payments can take a couple of days to clear.

Even if it was late, there is no reason b to assume you'll never get paid or that you'll always be paid late.

Comment: I dont know about other countries but in a country like Sweden it is very bad to not be paid on the date your contract states is your salary day. As an employee you have right to get interest from the first day after your salary day.

Comment: @novafluff In Australia, bank transfers take a couple of days to clear.

Answer (score 2):

When there is a pay issue always start with the company. It is fine that you asked co-workers, but you need to talk to somebody that understands the payroll system.

> I started a new job recently

If this is your first payday with them, there can be hiccups. Depending on when the bank information was given to payroll, it is possible that pay could be delayed, or a check generated instead. Again payroll will know, or be able to research your situation.

There is also a possibility that the banking information was incorrect. Again check with payroll, but also contact your bank. They should be able to do some research on their side if payroll said the money has been sent.